# How to receive data from input to div

Tags: jquery

I want to show data to div not textarea how do it..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
        var $pastable = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#target").val($pastable.val());
            $pastable.val("");
            $pastable.focus();
        }, 100);
    });

});
</script>
```

Paste here: `<input id="pasteable" />`

It should show here instead:

```
<textarea id="target"></textarea>
```

How to show in this div

```
 <div id="target"contentEditable="true"style="width:300px;height:100px;border:1px #ffccff solid"></div>
```

Comment: your `#target` element is a `div`, so you must use method `.html()` instead of `.val()`: `$("#target").html($pastable.val())`.

Answer (score 2):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dr5kf/)**

Your `#target` element, isn't `textarea` anymore, so you must use `.html()` method instead of `.val()` method.
Consider the following markup:

```
<input id="pasteable" />
<div id="target"contentEditable="true"style="width:300px;height:100px;border:1px #ffccff solid"></div>
```

And in your JS code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
        var $pastable = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#target").html($pastable.val());
            $pastable.val("");
            $pastable.focus();
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you It's very good for work,,and if i want to recive data from $.post("re.asp",{ste:title},function(data) how to insert this function

Comment: @วาวาวา Then, you must work with the `data` parameter passed to the callback in your `$.post()`.

Comment: can't do it..<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {
    $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
        var $pastable = $(this);
  $.post("re.asp",{ste:pastable},function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#target").html($pastable.val());
           // $pastable.val("");
            $pastable.focus();
        }, 100);
    });});
});

</script>
Paste here: <input id="pasteable" />
<span id="target"></span>

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 elements with the same `id` on the page. Change either one of them accordingly, for example:

```
<textarea id="source"></textarea>
```

And:

```
<div id="target" contentEditable="true" style="width:300px;height:100px;border:1px #ffccff solid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use same Id in a `form`. But if you have some requirement then use as-

```
  $(window).load(function () {
    $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
    var $pastable = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("[id='target']").val($pastable.val());
        $pastable.val("");
        $pastable.focus();
    }, 100);
  });

});
```